# Current pending sector is 2 but cannot be reproduced

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

- `smartctl` shows "No Errors Logged"

  > ```
  > SMART Error Log Version: 1
  > No Errors Logged
  > ```
- `smartctl -t long` results in "Completed without error"

  > ```
  > SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
  > Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)    LBA_of_first_error
  > # 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     62403
  > ```
- `badblocks /dev/sdX` output is empty
- `smartctl -a /dev/sdX` still reports 2 pending sectors

> ```
> SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
> Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
> ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
>   1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       83
>   3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   162   155   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2883
>   4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       228
>   5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
>   7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
>   9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   015   015   000    Old_age   Always       -       62765
>  10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
>  11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
>  12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       213
> 192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       185
> 193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       228
> 194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   096   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       47
> 196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
> 197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
> 198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
> 199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
> 200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
> 240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   020   020   000    Old_age   Always       -       59081
> 241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       30531542435
> 242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       24112322174
> ```

- I keep getting emails about SMART errors

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1218312/pending-sector-issue-does-this-mean-the-hdd-is-failing/1218317#1218317